# "What to call it" vs. "how to call it"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I went through the questions, but I didn't find an answer to this kind of sentence. Would you tell me what would be the correct sentence A or B? I had 2 beta readers and 2 answers. Thank you.

A) It was one of those last beautiful days of an Indian Summer, and the universe — or fate, you decide what to call it — had other plans for her.

B) It was one of those last beautiful days of an Indian Summer, and the universe — or fate, you decide how to call it — had other plans for her.

Comment: What is a "beta reader"? And definitely "what" not "how".

Comment: Thank you. A 'beta reader' is a person who can read (for free or no) your manuscripts-drafts.

Comment: I think the more common term (at least in English) for that is probably "proofreader", BTW.

Comment: @Foogod No, it's most definitely ***beta*** *reader*. It's a specific industry term, and it's something completely different from a proofreader. Beta readers help authors polish their work (at a high level) before it even gets to the editing or publishing stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the direct answer to your question:

> ... and the universe — or fate, you decide what to call it ... *(correct)*

is the correct way to say this.

> ... and the universe — or fate, you decide how to call it ... *(incorrect)*

is not grammatically correct.

In English, the phrase "how to <do something>" is often explained as meaning something like "in what way", but more specifically, it almost always means more along the lines of "by what process or procedure".

As such, saying "how to call it", actually means "by what procedure you call it", which particularly in the case of the verb "call", usually means something substantially different:

> Q: Do you know what to call that animal?
>
> A: Yes, that is called an "emu".

whereas:

> Q: Do you know how to call that animal?
>
> A: No, I'm afraid I have no idea how to get it to come over here.